# How to index and search "Public Pages" in Liferay 6?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am fairly new to liferay so please bear with me if this is a naive question.

As far as I know, Liferay automatically indexes some out of the box items (core portlets) such as Web Content, Bookmarks, Users etc.

What I need to do is index "public pages" (see screenshot).  When I create a new public page with some custom fields, I want to be able to index this in Lucene with Title and Description and be able to search for it as you search other out of the box assets.

[image]

I understand that you can write an indexer for a custom portlet, but Public Pages are something completely different.

How can I index them on creation/update so I can search from Lucene? I will appreciate any help with this.

Comment: I haven't used indexing a lot but I'd search for the portlet that can add new public pages, it should be somewhere under `liferay-portal-src-6.1.1-ce-ga2\portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\sites_admin`or something. Then use your `ext` environment to hook it so you can add new entries to your Lucene index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay pages are nothing but a Liferay object `Layout`. Do this

- Create a Liferay Hook plugin and override the `LayoutLocalService`.
- Modify the `addLayout` method and with the appropriate condition (identify the public page)
- Call `SearchEngineUtil` class and call `addDocument` method to save the data into index.

Hope this helps.